# can't disable viewpager swipe programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `Fragment` inside my app which contains a `ViewPager`. I have a `String` variable code. If `code` equals "NBG" I want to disable swipe of the `ViewPager`.

```
public class CurrencyFragment extends BaseFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currency_layout, container, false);

        mViewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.Detailpager);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            code = object.getCode();
        }

        if (code.equals("NBG")) {
            CustomViewPager pager = new CustomViewPager(getActivity(), null);
            pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        } 

        return view;
    };


public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using two different `ViewPager`s. The `ViewPager` that's initialized using `View.findViewById` isn't the same as the `CustomViewPager` being created when `code.equals(NBG)`.

In `fragment_currency_layout` instead of using `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`, use `path_to_CustomViewPager`. Then call `mViewpager.setPagingEnabled` instead of `pager.setPagingEnabled`.

Comment: I tried the following way but I cant call this method on mViewpager.

Comment: You either need to cast `CustomViewPager` when you're calling it, or instead of declaring `mViewPager` as `ViewPager`, use `CustomViewPager` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`mViewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.Detailpager);`

In your XML layout, where you declare your ViewPager, you should declare your CustomViewPager instead. CustomViewPager will need to be in its own file.

Currently, you are instantiating the regular ViewPager (I assume, as you haven't given the XML code). Then you do:

```
CustomViewPager pager = new CustomViewPager(getActivity(), null);
pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

But this is an extra ViewPager you've instantiated which isn't related to any UI in your screen.